# Unhandled exceptions in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, exception

I have created a public Web App with access to my private spreadsheet data. I can catch and log exceptions in`try..catch`, but:

1. is it possible to catch all unhandled exceptions, like browsers `window.onerror`?
2. can I view logs of unhandled exceptions somewhere?
3. by exceptions like "Service invoked too many times" my app is even not getting run, so here I definitely can`t handle the exceptions. Is there logs with such kind of exceptions?

*These are so simple questions, so that I'm bit confused to ask them, but after hours of research I could not find the answers.*

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The "Service invoked too many times" error is a server error.  Are you using `try{ .. } catch(e) { sendTheDeveloperTheError(e.message) }` in the .gs server code?  You should have a script function that does nothing but inform you of server errors.  You can do something like email yourself with the error, or log the error to a spreadsheet you own.  Errors in the browser can be caught, then sent to the server with `google.script.run.sendClientError(e)`  Then you need a function `sendClientError()` in a script file.

Comment: @SandyGood, where can I see if and which server errors have occured for my script? And yes, I use the `try..catch` blocks, but this doesn't help for server errors. And also sometimes I can forget some `try` statements, or in a `catch` block uncaught exception can occure, but then we cann`t log that uncaught exceptions. But you are right, on client side we receive all the exceptions, and can send the errors back. But do we have to use the log script within other web-app/other account, while when we reached the google quoatas, then we cann`t access that backend logger also. What do you think?

Comment: It would be very good, if there were a way to process errors without needing to use `try . . . catch` but I don't know of any way that is possible.  If that is what you are asking.  You can automatically catch server errors that happened from using a `google.script.run.yourScriptFunctionName()` call from the client by using `withFailureHandler(name_of_client_function)`  [Link to Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withFailureHandler(Function))  I still don't know exactly what you are using?  Apps Script Web App?  Sheets API?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

These are issues that are being addressed currently. Right now in the Apps Script Early Access Program are two new additions that handle these cases. The first is native integration with stackdriver logging and the addition of `google.script.run.withLogger()`.

First off for now you need to apply for the EAP:

> > https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/apps-script-eap

### Stackdriver Logging:

To log to stackdriver the `console` object has been added to the server side.

code.gs

```
console.log('This will log to stackdriver')
```

Check out the docs for all the methods of `console`.

> > https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#stackdriver_logging

Example from the docs:

```
function measuringExecutionTime() {
  // A simple INFO log message, using sprintf() formatting.
  console.info('Timing the %s function (%d arguments)', 'myFunction', 1);

  // Log a JSON object at a DEBUG level. The log is labeled
  // with the message string in the log viewer, and the JSON content
  // is displayed in the expanded log structure under "structPayload".
  var parameters = {
      isValid: true,
      content: 'some string',
      timestamp: new Date()
  };
  console.log({message: 'Function Input', initialData: parameters});

  var label = 'myFunction() time';  // Labels the timing log entry.
  console.time(label);              // Starts the timer.
  try {
    myFunction(parameters);         // Function to time.
  } catch (e) {
    // Logs an ERROR message.
    console.error('myFunction() yielded an error: ' + e);
  }
  console.timeEnd(label);     
  }
```

In addition you can also check `Log Exceptions` in the scripts properties. This will generate a stackdriver entry every time any error occurs in your script.

### Error recovery in a web app

To recover in a web app from a failure you have access to the `withFailureHandler()` method found in the `google.script.run` object. With this you can register a callback in the event your script hits an exception.

Full documentation can be found at:

> > https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run

If you are doing server side checks with `try...catch` you may be getting an exception but gracefully handling it. In this case withFailureHandler() will not execute and onSuccessHandler() propably isnt the best place to handle errors. In the EAP there is now a `withLogger` method to `google.script.run`. For now there no documentation for `google.script.run.withLogger()`. I found it by digging through devtools. `withLogger()` allows you to register a function as a callback when ever a stackdriver entry is created. This is particularly helpful when you have `log exceptions` checked in your script properties. In this sense it is a bit like `withFailureHandler()` but it can be triggered by any stackdriver entry you add though the server-side `console` object.

index.html

```
<script>
  google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function(){console.log('OK')})
        .withFailureHandler(function(e){console.error(e)})
        .withLogger(function(e){console.warn("The following log was generated:"+e)})
        .serverFunctionCall();
</script>
```

code.gs

```
function serverFunctionCall(){
   console.log("This log will generate a callback");
   return true;

}
```

Comment: Thank you, Stackdriver Logging is the solution for me.  It logs also all unhandled exceptions. But the Option should be checked in Scripts Preferences > Log exceptions.

Comment: This is a godsend, especially after they trimmed the Execution Transcript logs - Logger.log().

Answer (score 0):

`Try/catch` at global scope will work, however any `let`/`const` container will not be globally exposed.

To fix this, you can use `var` within the `try/catch` at global scope